# Заполнение многомерного массива методом array_push

Tags: php, json

Заполняю массив перед выдачей в формате JSON таким образом:

```
$json_data = array('from_login'=>$rows[$j]['from_login'],
                               'message_enc_from_key'=>$rows[$j]['message_enc_from_key'],
                               'who_login'=>$rows[$j]['who_login'],
                               'message_enc_who_key'=>$rows[$j]['message_enc_who_key'],
                               'date_time'=>$rows[$j]['date_time']
                               );
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Возник вопрос как можно заполнить данный массив методом array_push. Пытался так:

```
array_push($json_data, 'from_login'=>$rows[$j]['from_login']);
```

Но выдаёт ошибку 500. Что я упустил и делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `array_push()` не предназначена для заполнения ассоциативных массивов, в результате ее работы получаются только индексные массивы. Если вы хотите добавить новый элемент в ассоциативный массив, лучше поступить так

```
$json_data['from_login'] = $rows[$j]['from_login'];
```